# I made a MERN stack but I have a problem with making roles for users. Any solutions?

Tags: reactjs, button, frontend, user-permissions

So I thought that I want to make roles for users, e.g Role1 can choose from AutoSearch field an employee and click the button with the possibility of writing a comment. Role2 can click the Comment button and click the 'Mechanic Tools' button. Role3 can click every button + a link from PrivateRoute which is 'Register'(adding a new employee to the database). For Role1 as you can realize it's impossible to click the Mechanic Tools button but its role can see the result of it. Additionally, the whole app has to keep the state of clicked buttons(buttons are like ON/OFF). I assume that I have to make those buttons sending state to MongoDB but I have no clue how to start with that roles thing.

I was trying to make that in MongoDB obviously but I didn't mean the database accessibility but the possibility of clicking each element in-app.

I mean these yellow buttons + the text field under the tire. Sorry that I dont write code but I have it in 3 different files and you might not understand what I mean.
https://gyazo.com/f604257b88efb04c64d04d73113e0125

I expect the possibility of logging in(I can do it now) as a user with a role assigned to its account with permissions.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Okay so.. I have a roles in Register form, right? I check one of them. How can I make that the created user will have that permissions? That user with Role1 can do this and that but cant do that, user with Role2 can do that, Role3 can do everything?

Comment: Put a flag on every single component/method you want to have variable permissions. You put the user info and its role your store/parent state, and then let the components react to the role value. Simple as that. Unfortunately this does not sound very secure, you may still want to validate the roles server-side and prevent certain methods from being executed in the back-end if the current user does not have the appropriate permission